# ActiveRecord raising exception on save without a bang in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my controller :

```
 @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password))
    if @user.save
      redirect_to(home_users_path, :notice => "Success")
    else
      redirect_to(new_user_path , :notice => 'Signup Failed.')
    end
```

but I am getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in UsersController#create.

I know the record is not unique, my question is I am using .save which should not generate any exception but return false. But in my application .save is behaving as save!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, when you have `validates :status, uniqueness: true` in the model , `save!` will raise an exception, but `save` won't.

But `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` is raised, because there's a uniqueness index on the column, so the validation is performed on database level. Just like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, when `find` method is called, though `find` is not a bang-method

Comment: Adding validates :email, :uniqueness : true solved my issue. I thought rails will be handling the db level exception on its own. Thanks alot!